# How to hold your hands during the amidah?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, hands-fingers

For someone praying the amiday by heart with eyes closed, what is the right way to hold your hands?

I know that the right hand should cover the left, but how exactly?

Can someone upload a diagram or a picture?

Comment: msh210, why is hands-fingers even a tag? :)

Comment: Check out the tag. There are quite a few questions there

Answer (score 4):

The Aruch Hashulchan 91:7 writes
כתבו רבותינו בעלי השולחן ערוך בסעיף ו:

> דרך החכמים ותלמידיהם שלא יתפללו אלא כשהם עטופים. ובעת הזעם יש לחבק
>   הידים בשעת התפילה כעבדא קמי מאריה. ובעת שלום יש להתקשט בבגדים נאים
>   להתפלל. עד כאן לשונו, וכבר כתבנו מזה. ו"חיבוק ידים" הוא שחובק אצבעות
>   ידיו זה בשל זה, כאדם ששובר אצבעותיו כשמצטער. ויש מהחכמים שהיו עושים כן
>   גם בעת שלום (רבא בשבת י א). ומכל מקום יש ליזהר שלא לחבוק אצבעותיו בעת
>   שלום, כי בזה מוריד דין על עצמו. אלא יניח ידיו זו על זו כפותין (הגר"ז).
>
> ואין טבעי בני אדם שוים בזה. ויש שקשה עליהם להתפלל באופן זה, אלא מניחים
>   הידים על הסטענדע"ר או על הדף הדבוק בכותל. ואין כלל קבוע בזה, וכל אחד
>   יעשה כפי מה שמוטב לו להתפלל באופן זה. ולא יתפלל בבתי ידים (האנטשו"ך).

my loose translation:

> In a time of tzaros one should interlock his fingers together.
>   However, in a time of peace one should not interlock his fingers since
>   it brings din on that person rather hand over hand is more
>   appropriate. Most people are not the same and some cannot concentrate
>   in this way rather one can place his hands on a shtender or a
>   protrusion from a wall. There is no set rule rather one should do what
>   he feels will help him the most in his prayers, and one should not
>   wear gloves while davening.

Comment: the set rule is to put your right hand over your left upon your heart

Comment: Did you read the Aruch Hashulchan,he brings that,however he writes practically there is no set rule

Comment: did you read what i wrote? the set rule is what i wrote as written in the jamaro and rambam and even shul7on 3oruch. what the 3oruch ha shul7on writes is from his own words and not the law of the jamaro. one can keep his hands how he likes when not praying properly, ie sick or disabled. anyone else is doing an 3aveiro:

Comment: שְׁמוֹנָה דְּבָרִים, צָרִיךְ הַמִּתְפַּלֵּל לְהִזָּהֵר בָּהֶן וְלַעֲשׂוֹתָן; וְאִם הָיָה דָּחוּק, אוֹ נֶאֱנָס, אוֹ שֶׁעָבַר וְלֹא עָשָׂה אוֹתָן--אֵינָן מְעַכְּבִין.  וְאֵלּוּ הֶן--עֲמִידָה, וְנֹכַח הַמִּקְדָּשׁ, וְתִקּוּן הַגּוּף, וְתִקּוּן הַמַּלְבּוּשׁ, וְתִקּוּן הַמָּקוֹם, וְהַשְׁוָיַת הַקּוֹל, וְהַכְּרִיעָה, וְהַהִשְׁתַּחֲוָיָה.

Comment: >אוֹ שֶׁעָבַר וְלֹא עָשָׂה אוֹתָן
..........
>תִּקּוּן הַגּוּף כֵּיצַד:  כִּשְׁהוּא עוֹמֵד בַּתְּפִלָּה, צָרִיךְ לְכַוַּן אֶת רַגְלָיו זוֹ בְּצַד זוֹ; וְנוֹתֵן עֵינָיו לְמַטָּה, כְּאִלּוּ הוּא מַבִּיט לָאָרֶץ; וְיִהְיֶה לִבּוֹ פָּנוּי לְמַעְלָה, כְּאִלּוּ הוּא עוֹמֵד בַּשָּׁמַיִם; וּמַנִּיחַ יָדָיו עַל לִבּוֹ כְּפוּתִין, הַיְּמָנִית עַל הַשְּׂמָאלִית.  וְעוֹמֵד כְּעֶבֶד לִפְנֵי רִבּוֹ, בְּאֵימָה וְיִרְאָה וּפַחַד.  וְלֹא יַנִּיחַ יָדָיו, עַל חֲלָצָיו.

Comment: You have a question on the Aruch Hashulchan,but that doesn't change wrote he wrote.

Comment: i dont have a question on him. and what i write doesnt change what he writes yes, but what he writes changes the halocho. and this is where my problem is

Comment: So you have a problem with the Aruch Hashulchan,not a question?

Comment: its not a question. i dont care for his reasoning as to why he diverted from the halocho. and its a pretty simple guess as to why he did so